# Flink state using RocksDB

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

What is the difference between using RocksDB to store operator state checkpoints vs using RocksDB as cache(instead of a cache like Redis)in Flink job? I have a requirement to store data processed from Flink job to a cache for 24 hours and perform some computations in streaming job based on that data. The data has to be removed past 24 hrs. Can RocksDB be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role that RocksDB plays in Flink is not really a checkpoint store or a cache. A checkpoint store must be reliable, and capable of surviving failures; Flink does not rely on RocksDB to survive failures. During checkpointing Flink copies the state in RocksDB to a distributed file system. During recovery, a new RocksDB instance will be created from the latest checkpoint. Caches, on the other hand, are a nice-to-have storage layer that can transparently fall back to some ground truth storage in the case of a cache miss. This comes closer to describing how the RocksDB state backend fits into Flink, except that Flink's state backends are essential components, rather than nice-to-haves. If the state for a running job can't be found in RocksDB, it doesn't exist.

Setting that aside, yes, you can store data in RocksDB for 24 hours and then remove it (or have it removed). You can explicitly remove it by using a [Timer with a KeyedProcessFunction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/), and then clear an entry when the Timer fires. Or you can use the [State TTL mechanism](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl) to have Flink clear state for you automatically.

You don't have to use Flink with RocksDB. The fully in-memory heap-based state backend is a higher performance alternative that offers the same exactly-once fault-tolerance guarantees, but it doesn't spill to disk like RocksDB, so you are more limited in how much state can be managed.